# Using Fancybox loaded async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fancybox

I am loading the Fancybox lib async inside a onload function:

```
function myLoad(){
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'miurl.com';
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[document.getElementsByTagName('script').length - 1];
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
}

<body onload="myLoad()">
```

The script is added to my head, but when i try:

```
$("#myDiv").fancybox();
```

After execute myLoad(), the console says "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in the fancybox plugin call.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You have to "wait" for the script to finish loading before trying to use it.  Loading something async means it will load in the background and finish loading sometime later while other things in the loading process continue.  If you have jQuery already available, you can use `$.getScript()` and use the success handler callback function to know when it has finished loading.

Comment: Thnaks $.getScript works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer since it solved your problem:

You have to "wait" for the script to finish loading before trying to use it. Loading something async means it will load in the background and finish loading sometime later while other things in the loading process continue.

If you have jQuery already available, you can use `$.getScript()` and use the success handler callback function to know when it has finished loading.

```
$.getScript(yourFancyBoxCodeURLHere, function() {
    $("#myDiv").fancyBox();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the call `fancybox();` is executed and inside is a problem. Than this function would be helpful ;-)

Or do you mean that `$("#myDiv")` is the problem, because why should this have a function `fancybox()`. It is hard to guess, with the little information you gave us.